# Чи правильним є слово ВЗАЄМОвідносини?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, росіянізм

Багато людей використовують слово *взаємовідносини*, і в художній літературі можна його зустріти. Але мені здається, що слово *відносини* вже саме по собі передбачає значення взаємності. Тож виходить тавтологія.  Знайшла також [інформацію](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/vidnosunu,-stosunku,-vzaemunu,-vidnoshennya,-stavlennya), що взаємовідносини - це русизм. Але в [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7775&page=286) це слово присутнє. То ж чи правильним є саме слово ВЗАЄМОвідносини? І чи не є калькою з російської?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Висловлю й іншу позицію.
У багатьох словниках зустрічається це слово, навіть без позначок **розмовне**.
У СУМ-11, у новішому СУМ-20, а також і в [Орфографічному словнику української мови](https://orfograf_ukr.academic.ru/16028/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8), [Орфоепічному словнику української мови](https://ukrainian_pronouncing.academic.ru/646/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8), [Українському тлумачному словнику](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/16704/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8), що посилається на Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.

Однак якщо звернутись до російсько-українських словників, то побачимо таке:

1. [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

   > Взаимоотноше́ния – **взаємовідно́сини**, обопі́льні відно́сини (стосу́нки), взає́мини.
2. [Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

   > **Взаємовідно́сини** – взаимоотношения.
3. [Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

   > Взаимоотношение – **взаємовідно́сини** (род. взаємовідно́син).
4. [Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

   > Завязать приятельские отношения с кем – заприятелювати з ким; зав’язати (іноді нав’язати) приязні **взаємовідносини** (відносини, стосунки) з ким.
5. [Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

   > взаимные отношения – взаємні відносини; стосунки; **взаємовідно́сини**, взаємини.

В англо-українських словниках теж це слово подається:

1. [Українсько-англійський словник 1955р. (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

   > **взає́мовідно́сини** (-син) pl = взає́мини; взаємоді́я (-і́ї) f, взаємоді́яння n reciprocal (mutual) action.
2. [Англо-український тлумачний словник економічної лексики 2004 (Анна Шимків](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

   > agreement 1. ком. угода; договір; 2. врр. згода; домовленість

> industrial ~ = угода про **взаємовідносини** робітників і роботодавців/

А також і на [цьому](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD&from_lang=uk&to_lang=en) сайті, однак уже у словосполученні:

> маркетинг **взаємовідносин** - relationship marketing

Отже, це все вказує на те, що слово є зафіксованим, літературним, словники подають його використання без жодних приміток. Однак сьогодні популярним є уникнення усіх подібних слів, які є в російській. Ймовірно (моя думка!), через це і "Уроки державної мови", і "Мова - ДНК нації" подають таке пояснення. Хоча, я все ж би уникала цього слова і замінювала на взаємини.

Comment: можна ще додати оцей словник: https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on, будуть не тільки переклади з російської тоді, і навіть тут є: https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&from_lang=uk&to_lang=en

Answer (score 2):

В [Уроки державної мови](http://compi.com.ua/uroki-derjavnoyi-movi-mova-kreschatic-kiev-ua-004-24-urok-24-y.html?page=45) знаходимо:

> **Відносини**
>
> “Який зміст передає слово відносини?”
>   У ХІХ – на початку ХХ сторіччя воно позначало не тільки взаємність у стосунках між людьми, а й ставлення особи (чи осіб) до когось. “Зрештою ми одне одному не заважаємо і тримаємося у гречних відносинах” (Леся Українка), “Мої відносини до панни Анелі тривожать мене” (Михайло Коцюбинський). 
>   У сучасній літературній мові цей іменник у значенні “ставлення” не виступає. Він поширений як термін у суспільно-економічній, виробничій сферах, у дипломатії. Суспільні відносини, дипломатичні відносини.

Так можна пояснити чому утворилося слово взаємовідносини.

А в [Народному оглядачі](https://www.ar25.org/article/vzayemyny-vidnosyny-stosunky-vidnoshennya-stavlennya.html) знаходимо таку інформацію:

> **Взаємини, стосунки** – вживаємо у значенні зв’язок між людьми. Взаємини підлітка з дорослими. Наші взаємини (наші стосунки). **Неправомірно вживати в цьому значенні слова взаємовідношення, відношення.**

Отже, слово **взаємовідносини** неправильно вживати у українській мові.